# Change javascript arrow function into typesctipt

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface, react-props, zustand

Grettings.

So I am trying typescript.
the initial code which I based on is on javascript

```
const PokemonTable = () => {
  const pokemon = useStore((state) => state.pokemon);
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);

  return (
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
        {pokemon
          .filter(({ name: { english } }) =>
            english.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
          .map(({ id, name: { english }, type }) => (
            <tr key={id}>
              <td>{english}</td>
              <td>{type.join(", ")}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

When I change it into typescript it throws these errors

[image: Error]

I tried to create an interface to pass the props to it

```
//interfaz de pokemon table
interface PkTableProps{
  id:number,
  name:Array<String>,
  type:Array<String>,
}
```

And then I applied to the arrow function

```
// pokemon table

const PokemonTable = (props : PkTableProps) => {
  const pokemon = useStore((state) => state.pokemon);
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);

  return (
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
        {pokemon
          .filter(({ props.name : { english } }) =>
            english.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
          .map(({ id, props.name: { english }, props.type }) => (
            <tr key={props.id}>
              <td>{english}</td>
              <td>{props.type.join(", ")}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

And I get these new syntax errors

[image: Error]

**NOTE**

In the line `<td>{english}</td>` on the table of the arrow function. I am doing it like that because I am trying to chose the name of each pokemon in english language. That means I want it as `key`

Here is the structure of the array of pokemons that I am using
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jherr/23ae3f96cf5ac341c98cd9aa164d2fe3/raw/0658aeff401d196dece7ec6fe6c726c6adc1cc00/gistfile1.txt

**This is the complete code**

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import create from "zustand";
// import { mountStoreDevtool } from 'simple-zustand-devtools';

const POKEMON_URL =
  "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jherr/23ae3f96cf5ac341c98cd9aa164d2fe3/raw/f8d792f5b2cf97eaaf9f0c2119918f333e348823/pokemon.json";

// definir el tipo de mi store
type State = {
  filter: string;
  pokemon: Array<string>;
  setFilter: (filter: string) => void;
  setPokemon: (pokemon: Array<string>) => void;
};

//interfaz de pokemon table
interface PkTableProps{
  id:number,
  name:Array<String>,
  type:Array<String>,
}


//tienda de estados
const useStore = create<State>((set) => ({
  // set initial values here
  filter: "",
  pokemon: [],

  setFilter: (filter: string) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      filter,
    })),

  setPokemon: (pokemon: Array<string>) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      pokemon,
    })),
}));

// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
//   mountStoreDevtool('Store', store);
// }

//  input
const FilterInput = () => {
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);
  const setFilter = useStore((state) => state.setFilter);
  return (
    <input value={filter} onChange={(evt) => setFilter(evt.target.value)} />
  );
};

// pokemon table

const PokemonTable = (props : PkTableProps) => {
  const pokemon = useStore((state) => state.pokemon);
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);

  return (
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
        {pokemon
          .filter(({ props.name : { english } }) =>
            english.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
          .map(({ id, props.name: { english }, props.type }) => (
            <tr key={props.id}>
              <td>{english}</td>
              <td>{props.type.join(", ")}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};


function App()  {
  const setPokemon = useStore((state) => state.setPokemon);
  

  //lifecycle hook every time the component renders

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch(POKEMON_URL)
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((pokemon) => setPokemon(pokemon));
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <FilterInput />
      
      </div>
      <h1>List of Pokemons</h1>
      <PokemonTable />
      {/* mostrar el resultado de filter */}
      {/* {filter}   */}
      {/* mostar lo que el contenido del array de la url */}
      {/* {JSON.stringify(pokemon)} */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You've declared `pokemon` as `Array<string>`, which it most certainly isn't. It's an `Array<PokemonEntry>` for some appropriate definition of `PokemonEntry` as an object. JS doesn't complain because it has no concept of types, but for TS you must declare the type correctly.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol  I changed it like this `pokemon: Array<PokemonEntry>;`. It throws this error  - `Cannot find name PokemonEntry`-. Should I Create this new element as an `Array<String>` ?

Comment: No. You need to declare what it is correctly. Looking at your code it seems you want `Array<PkTableProps>`, but even that is declared incorrectly. `name` should be `{[lang:string]: string}` and `type` ideally should be an array of enum entries. Furthermore it's missing `base` altogether, which should be itself an object with the appropriate keys mapped to `number`s.

Answer (score 0):

```
type State = {
  filter: string;
  pokemon: Array<string>;
  setFilter: (filter: string) => void;
  setPokemon: (pokemon: Array<string>) => void;
};
```

This type says that the `pokemon` property of your store is an array of `String` (which should be the lowercase `string` instead).

```
pokemon.filter(({ name: { english } }) =>
```

This function treats each element of the `pokemon` array as an object with a `name` property. The `name` itself is as an `object` with a property `english` which is a `string`.

These are two different and incompatible types, which is why you have an error.

---

You need to figure out which one is correct and which one is the mistake.  The linked `.txt` file helps with this. A Pokemon object looks like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: {
    english: "Bulbasaur",
    japanese: "フシギダネ",
    chinese: "妙蛙种子",
    french: "Bulbizarre"
  },
  type: ["Grass", "Poison"],
  base: {
    HP: 45,
    Attack: 49,
    Defense: 49,
    "Sp. Attack": 65,
    "Sp. Defense": 65,
    Speed: 45
  }
};
```

So we can see that the `name` property is an object with a property `english` -- **not** an `Array<string>`.

It is up to you how specific you want to be about your types.  You could describe the `name` property as

```
type Name = Record<string, string>
```

which is an object whose keys and values are both `string`.  This means that any `string` can be used as a key.  So you might want to be more specific and say that it's an object that looks like this:

```
type Name = {
  english: string;
  japanese: string;
  chinese: string;
  french: string;
}
```

This would give you an error if you try to access an invalid key, like `name.spanish`.

---

The `pokemon` property of your `State` is an `Array` but it's not an array of `string` -- it's an array of pokemon objects.  We need to define the type for a `Pokemon` based on your data file.

```
type Pokemon = {
  id: number;
  name: {
    english: string;
    japanese: string;
    chinese: string;
    french: string;
  };
  type: Array<string>;
  base: {
    HP: number;
    Attack: number;
    Defense: number;
    "Sp. Attack": number;
    "Sp. Defense": number;
    Speed: number;
  }
}
```

Your `State` type can use this `Pokemon` type:

```
type State = {
  filter: string;
  pokemon: Array<Pokemon>;
  setFilter: (filter: string) => void;
  setPokemon: (pokemon: Array<Pokemon>) => void;
};
```

Since you are using the generic `<State>` on your `create` function, you can fix the errors that pop up by removing the types on the arguments.  They will be inferred correctly from your `State` type.

```
const useStore = create<State>((set) => ({
  // set initial values here
  filter: "",
  pokemon: [],

  setFilter: (filter) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      filter,
    })),

  setPokemon: (pokemon) =>
    set((state) => ({
      ...state,
      pokemon,
    })),
}));
```

In your first version the `PokemonTable` did not take any props.  This one is closer to correct.  So you can delete your `PkTableProps` interface.  All of the data that you need comes from the store rather than from props.

Now that the `State` has the correct types, your initial `PokemonTable` component works!

```
const PokemonTable = () => {
  const pokemon = useStore((state) => state.pokemon);
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);

  return (
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
        {pokemon
          .filter(({ name: { english } }) =>
            english.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
          .map(({ id, name: { english }, type }) => (
            <tr key={id}>
              <td>{english}</td>
              <td>{type.join(", ")}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

The nested destructuring of `.filter(({ name: { english } })` might be hard to read.  It may be easier to understand if you write it like this.

```
const PokemonTable = () => {
  const pokemonArray = useStore((state) => state.pokemon);
  const filter = useStore((state) => state.filter);

  return (
    <table width="100%">
      <tbody>
      {pokemonArray
          .filter(pokemon =>
            pokemon.name.english.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase())
          )
          .map((pokemon) => (
            <tr key={pokemon.id}>
              <td>{pokemon.name.english}</td>
              <td>{pokemon.type.join(", ")}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

---

One last thing -- you only need your `useEffect` which fetches the pokemon data to run once. You can give it an empty dependency array `[]` or a dependency array with `[setPokemon]`.

[Working CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/zustand-typescript-pokemon-kbupj?file=/src/App.tsx)